# Unable to install mysqlclient on ubuntu using pip

Tags: python

I have a following problem. I would like to install MySQLdb. I try `pip install mysqlclient` but  I got this error message:

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.1.1.tar.gz (88 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ydedt20p/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ydedt20p/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-ydedt20p/mysqlclient/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ydedt20p/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (15 lines):
    /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: mariadb_config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ydedt20p/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ydedt20p/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 70, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs")
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ydedt20p/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
        raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
    OSError: mysql_config not found
    mysql_config --version
    mariadb_config --version
    mysql_config --libs
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I am using Python 3.8 on Ubuntu. How can I fix it, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read and follow the [installation instructions for Linux](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/blob/main/README.md#linux).

For Ubuntu,

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential
```

to install the required libraries before attempting to

```
pip install mysqlclient
```